# Segmented control on top of a table view, not in the title view though

Tags: ios, view, tableview, title, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I put a segmented control on top of a tableview. I don't want it on the title view of the navigation controller and I don't want it to scroll with the tableview either. For reference of what I mean, please look at App Store app, choose Categories, then select any category. There you will see the segmented control I'm looking for. The one with 'Paid', 'Free', and 'Release Date' segments. I'm using the code not IB, so if you know how please answer this with code not IB drag and drop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you need other components in a table view controller other than the table view, you can't use a **UITableViewController**. You need to use a **UIViewController**. You add the **UITableView** as a subview and you make the view controller the table view's data source and delegate. Then you can add any other components to the view controller's view as well. This way the additional components don't scroll with the table view. There's a little more plumbing to do to get the view controller to behave exactly like a table view controller. This includes overriding the `setEditing:animated:` method to set the editing property of the table view. It includes deselecting any currently selected row in the `viewWillAppear:` method.

**UITableViewController** has the table view as its view. This prevents you from adding any other subview to the table view controller in a way that they won't scroll.

Comment: It worked out very well. It was much easier than I thought. Thanks a lot rmaddy!