# How to add multiple cells in header of a table view (not section header)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I would like to implement segmented controls like this (circled with red) :

[image]

(When we scroll this view, the segmented controls stay sticky at the top of the view, that makes me think it's a cell on its own ? but I may be wrong).

I have already implemented a custom cell (that displays kind of what is above the red ellipse in the above picture, in purple) and add it to the header of my table view like so :

```
BigCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BigCell"];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = cell;
```

Now, I think I should create a second cell with the segmented controls in it and add it also to the table header (and not in the section header, because I have many sections with their titles).

Then, I would create a UIView containing this two cells and add this view as the header of my tableView ? Is this a correct way to do it ?
Thank you very much for the help !

Comment: So are you asking how to add a UISegmentedControl to a view? Or how to make the view stick to the top of the table view?

Comment: @Steve_Wilford Sorry for being unclear, I'm asking, first, how is (probably) implemented the segmented controls in the example picture posted above ? I was thinking in the table header view but I have already put a cell in it. And secondly, how can I make this segmented controls stick to the top.

Comment: It is hard to say exactly what is happening in the example you have given. But what you want to do is certainly possible if you add it to a section header in a tableView.

Comment: @Reveclair Hi. Just merge the BigCell and SegmentedControl together in the single view. And it is better to use the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` instead `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options.

1) Make a container view to host both of your "cells" (which needn't be UITableViewCells - just views...).  Add the singular container view as the table header.

2) Forego using the table header altogether and just place your views above the table, making it shorter.  This is more complicated if you're using a UITableViewController, but simple if you're just hosting a UITableView in some other custom UIViewController.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I may consider your second solution, as it seems it can make the segmented controls stick to the top (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993212/segmented-control-on-top-of-a-table-view-not-in-the-title-view-though). However, it will also make, what I called the big cell in purple, stick to the top too ? considering these 2 views will be outside of the tableview. Thanks again.

Comment: You can lay it out however you want.  Use auto layout in Interface Builder to define a couple constraints for your three views - purple, segmented, tableview.  If you go this route don't use a UITableViewController!

Answer (score 0):

this is an example with uilabel that stick to the top - just change it to your uisegmentedcontrol

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *viewForSectionHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, SETTINGS_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
    [viewForSectionHeader setBackgroundColor:[Utils colorHeaderBlue]];
    UILabel *lblSectionTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, SETTINGS_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
    lblSectionTitle.text = @"PROFILE";
    lblSectionTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lblSectionTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [viewForSectionHeader addSubview:lblSectionTitle];

    return viewForSectionHeader;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I've tried it. But given that I have many sections in my tableView, each one with a title, that will not make it. Besides, what makes this header sticky in your code ? Thank you !